# Hibernate and composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and Oracle database and just got stuck.

I'm trying to map this table:

```
CREATE TABLE passengers_on_the_flight
(
    flight_id   NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES flight(flight_id),
    passenger_id    NUMERIC(20) REFERENCES passenger(passenger_id),
    seat        NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,        
    CONSTRAINT "not free" PRIMARY KEY (flight_id,passenger_id,seat) 
);
```

So my mapping class looks like:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "PASSENGERS_ON_THE_FLIGHT")
 @NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "PassengersOnTheFlight.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM PassengersOnTheFlight p")})
public class PassengersOnTheFlight implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@EmbeddedId
protected PassengersOnTheFlightPK passengersOnTheFlightPK;
public PassengersOnTheFlightPK getPassengersOnTheFlightPK() {
return passengersOnTheFlightPK;
}
public void setPassengersOnTheFlightPK(PassengersOnTheFlightPK passengersOnTheFlightPK) {
this.passengersOnTheFlightPK = passengersOnTheFlightPK;
}

@JoinColumn(name = "SEAT", referencedColumnName = "SEAT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int seat;


@JoinColumn(name = "FLIGHT_ID", referencedColumnName = "FLIGHT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Flight flight;


@JoinColumn(name = "PASSENGER_ID",referencedColumnName = "PASSENGER_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne 
private Passenger passenger;

//Getters, setters for seat, flight and passanger
```

And primary key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PassengersOnTheFlightPK implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "FLIGHT_ID",nullable=false)
private long flightId;


@Column(name = "SEAT",nullable=false)
private int seat;

@Column(name = "PASSENGER_ID", nullable=false)
private Long passengerId;  

//Getters and setters for seat, flightId and passangerId
```

I tried to persist something and got

```
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

That because Hibernate generates such query:

```
insert into PASSENGERS_ON_THE_FLIGHT (seat, FLIGHT_ID, PASSENGER_ID, SEAT) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I don't get why. Did I mis something in the mapping classes?

Comment: Why is seat part of the primary key? passenger_id and flight_id should be sufficient.

Although I do agree with Paul that it would be a better design to have an identity key on the table. Makes things far simpler.

Comment: Also, seat should be annotated as @Column, not @JoinColumn

Answer (score 3):

I get the same problem with a Coposite Key and solved it adding this params at the @JoinColumn hibernate annotation in the get methods of the external PK duplicate entities:

@JoinColumn(...**, updatable=false, insertable=false**)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate really REALLY wants you to have a unique identity key for each table; it has "issues" without it.  Try putting an identity key on your table.

Comment: He does have embedded key. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You get your error because you specified seat twice. Once you have it as property of your entity `PassengersOnTheFlight` and second time in the key. If it is part of your key, remove it from the main object. If it is an integer, you probably don't want `@JoinColumn` for it anyway.